# How to calculate volume and surface area of three dimensional figures given set of three dimensional coordinates?

Tags: surfaces, volume, computational-geometry

I have set of three dimensional coordinates, and the shape is unknown. I would like to calculate the surface area and volume for these coordinates approximately. What is the right approach to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that the shape is a convex polyhedron and the given coordinates are of its vertices, or something else?

Comment: Can you tell us what the set is? The "shape" is most likely implicitly given in the definition of the set.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Yeah, its a polyhedron and coordinates are vertices.

Comment: @graydad, the set is coordinates of a particular place. x,y are the point coordinates, and z being the depth. I want to calculate the volume and surface area approximately.

Comment: @user10550 ok I understand that part, I mean is the set defined as something like $$S = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \}$$

Or are you just told you have some points?

Comment: oh ok, got it, no the points are defined to be just integers, and I dont have any other information.

Comment: Everyone: it seems that the "shape" is the convex hull of the given points: the smallest convex 3-D set that contains the points. That means "that the shape is a convex polyhedron and the given coordinates are of its vertices." This shape is well defined, even if it is hard to pin down in general from the given points. So the problem is theoretically do-able, though difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have done similar problems in two dimensions, I have never done this in three.

But it seems to me that the problem of finding the surface area and volume of the convex hull (convex polyhedron) of a given finite set of points defined by their coordinates is do-able but difficult. The hard step is the first: given the points, find the triangles that make up the sides of the polyhedron. (A side may be a polygon with more than three sides, but that polygon can be broken up into triangles, so the triangles can be found for any convex polyhedron.) Given that, finding the surface area and volume are [not difficult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume).

However, I have no idea for a practical algorithm to find the bounding triangles for the polyhedron in the general case. An impractical algorithm for many points is to check every combination of three non-collinear points from the set, and see if all the other points lie on one side of the plane defined by those points. If so, that would be a bounding triangle. You would need to check for co-planar triangles resulting from this, and find non-overlapping triangles for the polygon. There are many sites that explain how to do [polygon triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Comment: I am able to figure out the faces of the polyhedron for my problem. Assume if I have a cube coordinates, and I have 3d coordinates, and faces of the cube. With that information, if I calculate the radius, and using that face information, I am planning to calculate the volume, is it right approach?

Comment: @user10550: I suppose that would work if you are sure that the figure is a cube. In the more general case, you don't even nee to find the center or radius of the polyhedron: just choose an arbitrary point, such as the origin, and add the pyramids made by each face and that point. Be sure to allow negative volumes: if the point is outside the polyhedron the negative ones will partly cancel the positive ones to give the correct total volume. If the point is inside the polyhedron then all pyramidal volumes would be positive.